# $.getJSON request does not run but next line of code does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a $.getJSON request that does not run but the line of code right after the request does. If I remove all the code after the $.getJSON request the request will run. How do I get the request to run iterate over returned data then run code following the request.

```
var eventList = new Array();
$.getJSON('../index.php?/home/events', function(eventItems){    
    $.each(eventItems, function() {
        var event = this;
        var eventItem = new Array();
        // format the date and append to span
        eventItem[0] = formatMDYDate(formatTimeStamp(this.loc_datetime, false), 0);
        // add shortdescription to div
        eventItem[1] = this.shortdescription; 

        // check if longdescription exist
        if (this.longdescription) {
            // create new anchor element for "More Info" link on events
            var link = $('<a></a>');
            link.attr('href', '../index.php?/home/event_info');
            link.addClass('popup');
            link.html('More Info');
            //link.bind('click', eventPopUp());
            link.bind('click', function() {
                var addressValue = event.id;
                dialog = $('<div></div>').appendTo('body');
                dialog.load('../index.php?/home/event_info', 
                    {id: addressValue});
                dialog.modal({
                    opacity: 80
                });
                return false;
            });
            eventItem[2] = link;
        }
        eventList.push(eventItem);
    });  
});
// removing the following lines of code will let the .getJSON request run
if (eventList.length > 0) {
    write_Events(eventList);
}
```

I have no idea what is causing this issue, please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asynchronous means that when you call it the JS runtime will not wait for it to finish before executing next line of code. Typically you need to use call backs in this case.

It's something like:

```
var a="start";
setTimeout(function(){
 a="done";
 dosomethingWithA(a);
},1000);
if(a=="done"){}//doesn't matter, a is not "done"
function dosomethingWithA(a){
 // a is "done" here
}
```

In your case the code should look something like:

```
var eventList = new Array();
$.getJSON('../index.php?/home/events', function(eventItems){    
    $.each(eventItems, function() {
        var event = this;
        var eventItem = new Array();
        // format the date and append to span
        eventItem[0] = formatMDYDate(formatTimeStamp(this.loc_datetime, false), 0);
        // add shortdescription to div
        eventItem[1] = this.shortdescription; 
        // check if longdescription exist
        if (this.longdescription) {
            // create new anchor element for "More Info" link on events
            var link = $('<a></a>');
            link.attr('href', '../index.php?/home/event_info');
            link.addClass('popup');
            link.html('More Info');
            //link.bind('click', eventPopUp());
            link.bind('click', function() {
                var addressValue = event.id;
                dialog = $('<div></div>').appendTo('body');
                dialog.load('../index.php?/home/event_info', 
                    {id: addressValue});
                dialog.modal({
                    opacity: 80
                });
                return false;
            });
            eventItem[2] = link;
        }
        eventList.push(eventItem);
    });
    processEventList();  
});
function processEventList(){
  // removing the following lines of code will let the .getJSON request run
  if (eventList.length > 0) {
    write_Events(eventList);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
var eventList = new Array();
    $.getJSON('../index.php?/home/events', function (eventItems) {
        $.each(eventItems, function () {
            //....
            eventList.push(eventItem);               
        });
        // removing the following lines of code will let the .getJSON request run
        if (eventList.length > 0) {
            write_Events(eventList);
        }
    });
```

Alternatively, you can use PubSub with jquery technique

```
 var eventList = new Array();
    $.getJSON('../index.php?/home/events', function (eventItems) {
        $.each(eventItems, function () {
           //....
            eventList.push(eventItem);               
        });            
        //publisher
        $(document).trigger('testEvent', eventList);
    });

    //subscriber
    $(document).bind("testEvent", function (e, eventList) {
        if (eventList.length > 0) {
            write_Events(eventList);
        }
    });
```

For more detials http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292151/PubSub-with-JQuery-Events

happy coding.. :)

Comment: I think you put the if statement in the .each body, should it not be out of the $.each(eventItems function body so the eventList array has been filled?

Comment: yes, eventList should be accessed from out of .each, I just edited thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` is an asynchronous call.  The callback will not execute until after the current function has executed completely.  The code after the call will always run BEFORE the `getJSON` callback runs.

Its possible the `write_Events` function is throwing an error and stopping execution, which is why the callback is never running.  Or it is actually running but you're not seeing evidence of it for whatever reason called by the extra code.

Answer (score 0):

javascript code never wait for the response from the server and we need to stop the processing of javascript  until we get the response from the server.

we can do this by using [jquery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)

You can also visit [this](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/) tutorial.

Comment: Actually you can make it wait for a response by setting async: false